# How To load On Premise sharepoint document libraries and subsites in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint

I am creating one WPF windows application where I need to display the content of on premise sharepoint  document libraries and sub sites and their documents in a wpf treeview control .

For example
Suppose this is my url for sharepoint
https://mysite.mycompany.com.when I go to this url in browser it displays me all documents and subsites for my user name

I would like same content in WPF treeview in a hierarchical way

Also When user clicks one folder all files/documents under that folder will display in a list view with metadata details
like created date,modified date etc

Please help me how to do this using c#

So far I have tried below code to get list of folders , but I am not sure how to get list of files and also how to get subsites

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List _lists = 
  clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
  clientContext.Load(_lists);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery query = new 
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection liCol = 
  _lists.GetItems(query);
   clientContext.Load(liCol);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem li in liCol)
   {
    }
```

Comment: You should specify things like whats the version of sharepoint? on premise or O365 etc

Comment: You should also provide at least what you have tried so far so we can supplement the code you provide

Comment: It is On premise share point site. so far I have tried below code to get list  but not sure if this is correct .

Also I am not sure how I can get the subsites

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List _lists = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
clientContext.Load(_lists);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection liCol = _lists.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(liCol);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem li in liCol)
{
}